# Logistic Population Growth Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Link found at: http://math.usu.edu/~powell/biomath/mlab3-02/node3.html

> One possible model for population growth is as follows: $\frac{dP}{dt}=rP(1-\frac{P}{K}), P(0)=P_0.$

In following the procedures to solve this logistic differential equation, I've stumbled upon the statement:

> Since there is no term with $P$ on the left hand side, we can see that $B-\frac{A}{K} = 0$ or $B=\frac{A}{K}.$

How did they suddenly agree on that $B-\frac{A}{K} = 0$? I agree with them that $1 = A+P(B-\frac{A}{K}),$ but my response was that they still need to *solve* for $A$ and $B.$

I understand that P(t) is a function; yet, when we plug in some $t,$ we will still get a *numerical* value for $P,$ which we need to solve for $A$ and $B.$ Instead, they say "since there is no term with $P$ on the left hand side, we can see..." and set $B-\frac{A}{K} = 0.$

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: The statement is an identity, i.e. True for all values of $P$. It's part of the partial fraction decomposition process

Comment: @Moo This may be a stupid question but bear with me; How do we know that $P(B-\frac{A}{K})$ is not contributing to the LHS? Is that because P(t) is a general function rather than a particular numerical value? Would it be different if P(t) was given as a numerical value at say t=2?

Comment: So, since there is only one way to make this identity true for all values of t, set the parenthesis to zero and solve for A. Great! That cleared it up.

Answer (score 1):

$$
1 = A + P(B- A/K)
$$
As $P$ varies, the left side does not change.  Therefore the right side does not change.  But the only way $P(B-A/K)$ could fail to change as $P$ changes is if $B-A/K$ is $0$.